# Extract error writing to oraociei12.dll while installing QGIS v.2.12.2-1

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I keep getting this error about 90% through the installation.  As per answer to another v. similar thread I have checked via Command Prompt tasklist/m function that there are no other processes or applications using the file.  So what now ? Any suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that library file is used in Oracle. Are you wanting to use this within QGIS? If not then you could consider installing and running the [OSGeo4W Network Installer](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

When you run it, select the **Advanced Install** option and follow through the instructions until you see the *Select Packages* menu. Type "oracle" in the search and select an option that doesn't involve installing it (e.g. `Skip` or `Keep` as shown in the red box).

[image: Select packages]

*Note: This is purely conjecture on my part as I haven't come across this issue before.*

Comment: Many thanks Joseph, I will give that a go as I don't need to use Oracle (best left well alone !).  I have successfully installed QGIS though on another, presumably 'cleaner' laptop so if it doesn't work all is not lost.  Thanks again, Alastair

Comment: @AlastairMorton - Most welcome buddy, glad you got installed! It's always handy having more than one computer at your disposal :)

Comment: I had the same problem. Used the the hint Joseph gave: install teh OSGeo4W Network Installer. It may have to do with Oracle conditions for usage as it came with an agree or not question for oracle usage even though I had already unchecked the oracle parts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with QGIS 2.18.12. Before there was installed version 2.18.11 which I deinstalled correctly. So I couldn't believe that oracle is the reason. In pure distress I **cleared up my C:-device**. This solved the problem.